# Datetime Formats

Tags: mysql, datetime

Mysql noobie here. I'm trying to load a csv file that has 2 types of date format: 1 is dd/mm/yyyy and the other is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.
I gather that mysql has a standard datetime format, which is different to both of these, but that you can use different formats by using a format statement.
What I don't understand (forgive how basic this is!) is how you go about it. Do I load the date as text, and then use the str_to_date function to  covert it to date format ie does the data type of everything in the column change to datetime? Or does the data remain as text, and is just formatted differently?

Comment: Investigate input re-processing in LOAD DATA syntax. You'd load custom date value into user-defined variable then parse it with STR_TO_DATE and save into proper column.

Comment: 'does the data remain as text' - If you the datatype loaded to is text then str_to_date won't change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE {filename}
INTO TABLE {tablename}
{options}
( {columns} , @datevalue, {columns} )      -- load custom value into user-defined variable
SET date_column = STR_TO_DATE(@date_value, '%d\/%m\/%Y') -- parse and save into the column
```

[LOAD DATA Statement # Input Preprocessing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing)

Comment: Thanks. Can I rather load the data and use the SET command later? I've been having several annoying problems using the LOAD INTO statement, to do with rights, and I'd rather just use a utility to do the load, and fix the data types thereafter.

Comment: @Walt If so then you may create additional column which will store customly formatted data. And, when this is possible, you'd update a table, convert your custom data and store it into date column. Also (I don't recommend this as a solution, but it is possible as temporary palliative) you may make your column datatype not DATE but VARCHAR - in this case you do not need in additional column, but you'd store mixedly formatted data in the column which is bad practice.